# Cannot connect to StrongLoop PM using StrongLoop Arc

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

I'm having trouble connecting to StongLoop PM using StrongLoop Arc. I'm following [these directions](http://docs.strongloop.com/display/SLC/Using+Process+Manager).

Here's what I tried:

```
# in one terminal window, I started up StrongLoop PM
$ nvm install v0.12.4
$ nvm alias default 0.12.4
$ npm install -g strongloop
$ slc loopback
> name: hello-strongloop
> directory: hello-strongloop
$ cd hello-strongloop
$ slc pm

# in another new terminal window, I started Arc
$ slc arc # enter login credentials, click process manager, and add pm host
> host: localhost
> port: 8701
```

After pressing the "connect" icon, I get a message under "App Status" saying:

```
unknown exception: invalid
Unknown "ServiceInstance" id "undefined".
```

Incidentally, the output in second terminal is:

```
$ slc arc
Loading workspace /home/s/strongloop/hello-strongloop
Embedded Process Manager [(none)]:  starting
StrongLoop Arc is running here: http://localhost:60520/#/
slc arc: StrongLoop PM v3.2.0 (API v5.1.0) listening on port `47743`
slc arc: listen on 47743, work base is `/home/s/strongloop/hello-strongloop/.strong-pm`
Embedded Process Manager [28647]:  started
Embedded Process Manager [28647]:  using port 47743
loopback-datasource-juggler deprecated Model hook "ManagerHost.beforeCreate" is deprecated, use Operation hooks instead. http://docs.strongloop.com/display/LB/Operation+hooks ../../.nvm/versions/v0.12.4/lib/node_modules/strongloop/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/dao.js:270:9
```

Comment: Running `slc pm` inside an app directory could cause problems because it will result in deployed apps seeing that app's dependencies. For what you are trying to do, you should probably be running it from your home directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build and deploy your Loopback application (using Arc) before you can manage the processes using Arc. Start Arc from your project directory by calling `$ slc arc`, and then from the web interface, click "Build and Deploy."

You'll also need to run `$ slc pm` from your home directory, not your project directory. This will solve the problem of the error message you're getting in Arc.